# The Dwarven Afterlife?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, planes, dwarf

I'm building a campaign and in it, my PCs need to retrieve the soul of a now-dead dwarven king. This mission would take them to one of the outer planes to find his soul and bring him back to the material plane. Which plane of existence serves as the afterlife for dwarves in the Forgotten Realms setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on which deity was the patron deity of the character.

The most likely location is Erackinor, the divine realm of Moradin, the head of the dwarven pantheon and his consort Berronar Truesilver. Moradin and Berronar are believed to have forged the dwarven race. In the Great Wheel cosmology, Erackinor is located on Solania, the fourth layer of Mount Celestia.

However if the soul was a follower of one of the other dwarven deities, it is also possible to be on another plane as well. Here is a list from 2e *On Hallowed Ground*:

- Abbator: Hades
- Clangeddin: Arcadia
- Dugmaren, Dumathoin, Vergadain: the Outlands
- Muamman: Ysgard

Comment: PS: I know the question is tagged 5e, but I don't think 5e has yet any material answering this question. For example, Moradin is described in MToF, but no information is given about his domain. Yet, since the 5e returned back to the 2e's Great Wheel Cosmology, I believe this answer from the lore should still be valid.

Comment: Yeah, 5e has very little content on planes for now, so the best we can do is to look for answers in older editions.

Comment: @ZwiQ I believe your comment should be in the answer directly , not in the comments section.